# СURL и Guzzle меняют порядок заголовков при запросе

Tags: php, curl, header, php-curl, guzzle

*Доброго времени суток.*

Пытаюсь отправить http-запрос со своим порядком заголовков, используя PHP.

CURL, **при отправке запроса, меняет порядок заголовков**. То же самое происходит при использовании библиотек, например Guzzle.
Мне обязательно нужно **сохранить последовательность**.

Можно ли как-то отключить эту "валидацию"?

Comment: Не используйте протокол http. Придумайте свой. В первый раз слышу о необходимости строго соблюдать последовательность заголовков

Comment: Если для HTTP нет необходимости строго соблюдать последовательность заголовков, тогда зачем она строго соблюдается и валидируется в этих библиотеках? Вопрос был как раз в том, как это отключить.

Comment: И вопрос был как это сделать, а не нужно ли мне это

Comment: Guzzle под капотом использует либо курл, либо стрим (stream_context_create) - следует из сорцов. Я проверил разные варианты, и с курлом все в порядке, отправляет как есть - проверял на https://httpdump.io. А вот в Guzzle есть предобработка заголовков `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MessageTrait`, и судя по коду, порядок действительно может быть другой. Напиши в вопросе минимальный воспроизводимый пример, что делаете, и ожидаемый порядок.

Comment: @ArchDemon The order in which header fields **with differing field names** are received is not significant - [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). Наверное ТС хочет отправить мультилайн заголовок, но подождем ответ на прошлый мой вопрос.